# finding dates and their position within a string using stanford nlp

Tags: groovy, nlp, stanford-nlp, date-parsing

I need to find the dates within a string and their positions. Consider the example string

"The interesting date is 4 days from today and it is 20th july of this year, another date is 18th Feb 1997"

I need the output (Assuming today is 2013-07-14)
2013-07-17, position 25
2013-07-20, position 56
1997-02-18, position 93

I have managed to write the code to get the various parts of the string that is recognized as date. Need to enhance/change this to achieve the above output. Any hints or help is appreciated:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new AnnotationPipeline();
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new PTBTokenizerAnnotator(false));
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new WordsToSentencesAnnotator(false));
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new POSTaggerAnnotator(false));
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));

    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("The interesting date is 4 days from today and it is 20th july of this year, another date is 18th Feb 1997");
    annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, "2013-07-14");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
    timexAnnsAll.each(){
        println it
    }
```

With the above code I get the output as:
4 days from today
20th july of this year
18th Feb 1997

EDIT::
Managed to get the date part, with the following change

```
timexAnnsAll.each(){it ->  
    Timex timex = it.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotation.class);  
    println timex.val + " from : $it"  
}
```

Now the output is:
2013-07-18 from : 4 days from today
2013-07-20 from : 20th july of this year
1997-02-18 from : 18th Feb 1997

All I need to solve now is to find the position of the date within the original string.

Comment: Does `println "pos:${it.beginPosition()} $it"` work?

Comment: @tim_yates, that does not work. Here it is of type edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation. That does not have any offset position value within it.

Comment: Just managed to get the date part working, all I need to solve now is to find the position of the matching date part within the input string. Editing the question to reflect this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each CoreMap returned in the list from `annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class)` is an `Annotation` and you can get other attributes of it, such as the list of tokens, each of which stores character offset information. So you can finish off your example like this:

```
List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
for (CoreMap cm : timexAnnsAll) {
  List<CoreLabel> tokens = cm.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
  System.out.println(cm +
          " [from char offset " +
          tokens.get(0).get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class) +
          " to " + tokens.get(tokens.size() -1)
          .get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation.class) + ']');
  /* -- This shows printing out each token and its character offsets
  for (CoreLabel token : tokens) {
    System.out.println(token +
            ", start: " + token.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class) +
            ", end: " + token.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation.class));
  }
  */
}
```

Then the output is:

```
4 days from today [from char offset 24 to 41]
20th july of this year [from char offset 52 to 74]
18th Feb 1997 [from char offset 92 to 105]
```